# Wordpress - Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server, wordpress

I just installed the plugin in the following site:

http://trucialstates.com/blog/

And everytime I try to register wih Facebook or Google+, it redirects to https://trucialstates.com/blog/ page with the following error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to littleblackbeautybook.com.
>
> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the
>   authenticity of the received data could not be verified. Please
>   contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
>   Alternatively, use the command found in the help menu to report this
>   broken site.

Beadvised I don't have SSL on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Speak to your webhost about a possible misconfiguration error. Note that Google directs users to secured versions of websites wherever possible, so if your webhost has misconfigured the server to make it seem like a secure version is available when it really isn't it'll cause problems.